# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_props' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to pass some data from state, as props to another component as follows:

```js
class Editor extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = {
      Data: null
    };
  }

  handleClick = () => {
    const fdata = this.props.fetchData(); //returns some data as array of objects
    this.setState({
      Data: fdata
    });
  };

  render() {
    <Overview sos={this.state.Data} />; //trying to pass Data from state to another component
  }
}
```

Getting an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_props' of undefined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all make your state object variables starting letter lowercase that is

`this.state = {data: null}`

Second your handleClick has async logic so make use of async and await. Like this -

```
handleClick = async () =>{
  const fdata = await this.props.fetchData(); //returns some data as array of objects
  this.setState({
     data: fdata
  });
}
```

EDIT: And as @rrd mentioned you need to return the jsx inside render

```
render{
  return(
     ....
 )
}
```

Comment: you're changing in `this.state` `Data` to `data`, but using in `this.setState()` `Data`... should be `data`. ;)

Comment: @sadi thanks for mentioning it. I forgot to change it there.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's a class you need to return something in the render:

```
render() {
  return (
    <Overview ...
  );
}
```

Is there something loading this class too, passing props into it?